# Ldap Authentication not working with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, active-directory, ldap

I am able to get LDAP authentication working with spring boot `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`. Same code works in other client environments, but somehow with one client it is not working.
I am able to connect to LDAP and bind and also reach the roodn, all is working fine.

In search filter, in place of using default one i.e.:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0}))
```

I am using:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))
```

I have tried a lot of search filters, but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone please help on this, don't have much knowledge on LDAP.

Comment: What are the logs saying ?

Answer (score 1):

The question is really if you should match by `userPrincipalName` or `sAMAccountName`. That really depends on what your users expect.

The `sAMAccountName` is what you would normally think of when you say "username".

The `userPrincipalName` looks like an email address. It's *usually* the same as the `sAMAccountName` followed by `@` and the domain DNS name, but it doesn't have to be.

You can see here for more information on that: [User Naming Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/naming-properties)

Whatever value the user types in as the username should match the attribute you have chosen here.

Answer (score 0):

@gariel user is expecting to strictly login only using sAMAccountName. I got the login working with email ID (&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName={0})) filter. But to make it work with sAMAccountName with their LDAP, changing it to (&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0})) just doesn't work. Their sAMAccountName and userprincipalname are not same.

As a work around, instead of completely depending on spring security for authentication,
user inputs the sAMAccoutName, and i intercept the request using a custom filter. In the custom filter, using JAVA code i query LDAP to provide me with the emailId of that sAMAccountName. Once i have the emailID of the user, i update the username field in the request from sAMAccountName to emailID and then proceed the authentication request forward(remember i already had the LDAP authentication working with emailID).

In SecurityConfig file : .addFilterBefore(new CustomFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
CustomFilter is where i am doing everything mentioned above.

Now everything works fine, but i have new issue. When user successfully authenticates, if user is not present in local db and doesn't require any authority it works fine. But the user is defined to be ADMIN in local db, and post authentication we provide it with the ADMIN authority, for some reason because of the custom filter it goes into a loop.